# hibernate cann't connect google could sql

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, smartgwt-pro

I'm working on smartgwt pro with a hibernate datasource. In development there is no no problem. When I deploy the app to Google there is a problem with the hibernate connection to Google Cloud SQL.

Here is my hibernate config:

```
<session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:google:mysql://jpacexpress:jpacdbinstance/jpac?user=root</property>

        <!-- 
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver</property>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpac</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:google:rdbms://jpacexpress:jpacdbinstance/jpac</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:google:mysql://jpacexpress:jpacdbinstance/jpac</property>
        -->

        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">xxxx</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">0</property>
```

I'm have tried changing the connection driver class and URL (see comments) . It also doesn't work.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: when i trying to config hibernate like this

Comment: when im trying to config hibernate like
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:google:rdbms://localhost/jpac</property>

its work , what i doing wrong ?

Comment: i got it now
my app on appengine is in US Region
my db instance is in Asia
so i need to change db instance to US and its work

Comment: What is the error message that you got in your App Engine logs?